# Beginner - Univariate Analysis

Tags: spss, univariate

I am trying to perform an analysis based on a survey response 'yes' vs 'no'. The response has multiple categories. For example, I am looking at a variable 'mechanism of injury' that has 4 categories, coded as numbers 1-4. I think the problem that I'm running into is that it would be more straightforward if the data was separated into different variables so I can deal with 0,1 variables.

Is there a way to still perform a chi-square test to compare if there is a difference between the survey response groups? Or do I have to separate these categories into separate variables?

I also see that a lot of papers have tables with separate p-values for every category and I was wondering if that wouldn't be the case for this dataset since I'd be getting a single p-value from the chi-square test.

I'm using SPSS v28

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I am very confused. Does your survey have yes/no variables (per your first sentence) or 1 through 4 answers (your 2nd sentence)?  What are these categories? 

And what are you trying to find out?

You can show part of your data, that would probably help.

Comment: I added a picture of the simplified data. As you can see, I have divided the groups based on survey responses, and retrospectively looking at the patient characteristics of each response group. The different disposition categories have a number assigned as ICU = 1, floor = 2, etc. Can I run a chi square test with this table? Or do I have to recode the variables into Home = 0, Other = 1, so on and so forth for all different categories?

Comment: You can do chi square on this table, but note that the numbers in parentheses are NOT percentages of anything that is in the table. Not row percentages, nor column, nor table. 

Maybe there are other rows or columns or NA or something?

Comment: Thanks - would I need to do a post hoc analysis to see which of the disposition categories is the one that is statistically significant? In terms of the percentage, there is a "total" column that I haven't included in the picture. Is that what you mean? Also to confirm, I'd need to do a fisher's exact test correct?

Comment: No that's not what I mean. Look at the percentages! They don't add to 100 in any direction.

Comment: Yes, the table is missing a few variables as it was just meant to show how it's set up overall. Thank you!